# Remove line from a file if a string is found

Tags: python-2.7, shell, csv, unix, sed

I have a `name.csv` file with data

```
x
y
z
```

I have another csv file `data.csv` from which the lines must be removed

```
a,20
b,30
x,40
y,50
z,60
```

I am trying to remove the string in `name.csv` from the `data.csv` file with following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r name
do
sed '/$name/d' data.csv
done <name.csv
```

The above shell script didn't work (no lines were removed from `data.csv` file). Can some help with this

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with `python`? Do you want a Python solution?

Comment: too many issues.. using shell loop, not using `-i` option for sed, not using variable substitution, etc... try `grep -Fvf name.csv data.csv > tmp && mv tmp data.csv` but wont necessarily match 1st column in data.csv... awk would be better choice for that

Comment: `sed '/name/d' data.csv` looks for literal `name`. You need to do variable substitution.

Comment: @JoeP edited. I meant $name. yeah `python` works as well. Thanks. I tried shell

Comment: Try double quotes. Required for variable substitution.

Comment: @Sundeep I tried it but didn't work

Comment: didn't work doesn't help.. what went wrong?

Comment: @Sundeep no line was removed

Comment: What if you have a line like `xx,123` in the second file, should it be removed?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { h[$1]; next } !($1 in h)' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
a,20
b,30
```

Answer (score 1):

Dead simple with `grep`:

`grep -vf name.csv data.csv`

Outputs:

```
a,20
b,30
```

Explanation:

- `grep -v` will output lines not matching any pattern given to grep
- `grep -f name.csv` uses name.csv as a pattern file
- So, `grep -vf name.csv` will output all lines matching no patterns in name.csv

If you want to match whole words and not substrings of words, you might try `grep -vwf` which adds the `-w` whole-word regexp option.

Comment: Oops, I see @Sundeep commented along these lines hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r name
do
sed -i "/${name}/d" data.csv
done <name.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, this could be done as follows:

```
import csv

# Read all names to be removed into a set
with open('name.csv') as f_name:
    names = set(row[0] for row in csv.reader(f_name))

# Read the data file and keep all entries not in the set
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f_data:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f_data)
    data = [row for row in csv_data if row[0] not in names]

# Reopen the data file and write all filtered entries back to the file
with open('data.csv', 'wb') as f_data:
    csv_data = csv.writer(f_data)
    csv_data.writerows(data)
```

`name.csv` can contain just the items to be removed, one per line, or be in the same format as `data.csv` in which case the first column entry is used.

For the data given, this results in an output `data.csv` containing:

```
a,20
b,30
```

Comment: I don't know python but when I executed this script, the lines were not removed

Comment: It was tested using Python 2.7.12, are you using Python 3.x?

Comment: I am using 2.7.12

Comment: Does `name.csv` contain any other column entries? I have updated the script to also work if `name.csv` is in the same format as `data.csv`.

Comment: name.csv contains only the strings I want to delete if found from data.csv
eg:
name.csv:
`a`
`b`
data.csv
`i,j`
`c,b`
`k,a`

Comment: The script should do exactly what you need. The script and files should be in the same folder, or alternatively add full paths to the filename.